# Editable PDF Files Rendering Blank on Preview

Tags: pdf, files, upload, preview

I hope this message finds you well. I have a question regarding an issue with the compatibility of PDF documents in the Salesforce document preview.

In our iOS app, we use editable PDFs with elements like text fields and checkboxes. When editing such a PDF in Adobe and uploading it to Salesforce, the content in text fields displays correctly. However, if the same PDF is edited in the Preview app on a Mac or in our iOS app and then uploaded to Salesforce, filled text fields appear empty. The content becomes visible only after downloading the document.

I'm reaching out to see if anyone has encountered a similar situation and if there are any solutions. We want to ensure our users can continue editing PDFs directly within our iOS app.

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Best regards,

Stanislav Holas